# Efficient way to retrieve data from multiple numpy memmap files and creating a new array

Tags: numpy, pytorch, numpy-memmap

for machine learning I need to get data from multiple large memmap files, combine them and return it.
The amount of variables (files) used are defined by the user.
At the moment I store the files in a list:
`memmap_path=["Folder1/file2.dat","Folder24/file28.dat","Folder65/file1.dat"]`

The data retrieval in the dataset class itself looks like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    list_of_arrays = [np.memmap(memmap_file, dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(24000,300,300))[index] for memmap_file in memmap_path]
    x = np.stack(list_of_arrays)
    y = self.targets[index]

    return torch.from_numpy(x), y
```

Does anyone have a better approach for the situation?
I am aware that using loops should be avoided if possible, but I am not sure how to do it in this case.
I thought about creating an array of zeros and filling it a loop, instead of using np.stack and list comprehension, but I am not sure about the performance improvements. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: First "avoiding loops" really only matters when you have a numpy array, and can do some sort 'whole-array' compiled operation on it.  Don't treat it as a "rule".  Weigh the the alternatives.

Comment: You don't have to recreate the `np.memmap`s in every `__getitem__` calls, rather do it in the `__init__`. But most importantly, you have `N` files of shape `K, H, W`, but `__getitem__` does indexing on the `K` dimension, resulting in an `N, H, W` tensor. You would be better if you could reformat your data into a `K` x `N, H, W` files.

Comment: @paime yes you are right, makes more sense to create the memmaps in the `__init__`. I also understand your point about the file system. The big problem is that I wanted to test different parameter combinations, meaning that `N` could change. Since I am currently still in the testing stage of things it would make sense to follow your suggestion.